# SQLAlchemy - mapping result from postgres function

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy, plpgsql

I've plpgsql function returning SETOF mytype, where mytype user defined type (set of columns).
I'd like to map result of this function to sqlalchemy object like this:

```
stmt = text("SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM myfunc(:name)")
stmt = stmt.columns(MyType.col1, MyType.col2, MyType.col3)
session.query(MyType).from_statement(stmt).params(page=1).all()
```

The question is how to define MyType in SQLAlchemy without defining table or view in database.